# Why didn't my quest get completed for the 100 diamonds after hatching the legendary monster?

Tags: tiny-monsters

I finally bred and hatched the legendary monster but once hatched, the quest for it (and the 100 diamonds, which was the reason i tried to get the legendary monster in the first place) still remains incomplete. Is this a glitch in my game? Should I try breeding and hatching another legendary to try and complete the quest again?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have clicked 'complete quest'